# Mathematica geometric plot issue

Tags: graphics3d, mesh

My first introdcution in mathematica resulted in following plot

```
Plot3D[(((-0.0023x^2+0.525x+1 )^2)((1-(((z)^2)/((12-((0.0006(180-x)^2-
0.1118*(180-x)+1)) )^2)))^0.5)),{x,0,180},{z,0,16},AspectRatio ->Automatic]
```

however the result gives me Plot issue. attached the out[] file

Looking for advice on how to solve these mesh issues at different small spots indicated in white. What did i overlooked from math point of view ?

[image]

Comment: Try: `Plot3D[(1 + 0.525 x - 0.0023 x^2)^2 (1 - 
    z^2/(11 + 0.1118 (180 - x) - 0.0006 (180 - x)^2)^2)^0.5, {x, 0, 
  180}, {z, 0, 17}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 100]`

Comment: In addition to increasing the `PlotPoints` recommend that you use `MaxRecursion->5`

Comment: Appreciated a lot

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Cross-posted: http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1312327

Comment: See http://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1423/4999

Answer (score 1):

`Plot3D`, because it samples only in the domain-plane (the `xz`-plane in the OP), has trouble resolving surfaces with tangents perpendicular to the domain-plane.  For functions whose gradients are not very large, `Plot3D` is usually superior to `ContourPlot3D`, but in this case, I think `ContourPlot3D` works better.

Even with the suggestions of `PlotPoints -> 100` and `MaxRecursion -> 5`, there are still some tiny but visible glitches in the surface mesh:

```
Plot3D[(((-0.0023 x^2 + 0.525 x + 1)^2) *
    ((1 - (((z)^2)/((12 - ((0.0006 (180 - x)^2 - 0.1118*(180 - x) + 1)))^2)))^(1/2))),
  {x, 0, 180}, {z, 0, 16},
  PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 5, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Medium, 
  ViewPoint -> {3.215347035920252`, 0.7760554973318896`, 0.7136394773692102`}
  ] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It is also necessary to square both sides to get rid of the square root.  (Sampling outside its domain and possibly rounding errors result in negative numbers under the radical, which causes `ContourPlot3D` trouble in resolving the surface.)

```
ContourPlot3D[y^2 == (((-0.0023 x^2 + 0.525 x + 1)^2)^2 *
     ((1 - (((z)^2)/((12 - ((0.0006 (180 - x)^2 - 0.1118*(180 - x) + 1)))^2))))),
  {x, 0, 180}, {z, 0, 16}, {y, 0, 958.5},
  MeshFunctions -> {#1 &, #2 &},
  MaxRecursion -> 2, BoxRatios -> {1., 1., 0.4}, ImageSize -> Medium, 
  ViewPoint -> {3.215347035920252`, 0.7760554973318896`, 0.7136394773692102`}
  ] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Amazing Feedback - the combination of Contourplot , Y square , the level of detail. Appreciated Your contribution a lot.

Comment: @user1542889 You're welcome!